# Como puedo lograr que la animación siga desde el punto donde quedo?

Tags: javascript

Este timer tiene una animación que usa la etiqueta de html `svg` y sus atributos `stroke-dasharray` y `stroke-dashoffset` . Con el primer atributo dibujo el perímetro de la circunferencia con azul y con el segundo lo uso para darle animación al timer y describir graficamente cuanto falta para que el timer llegue a 0. Me gustaría que cuando se pare la animación no empiece de nuevo desde el inicio de la circunferencia sino que continúe desde el punto donde quedo al hacer click en el botón pause, hasta completar el tiempo restante. Como puedo hacerlo?

```js
class Timer {
  constructor(durationInput, startButton, pauseButton, callbacks) {
    this.durationInput = durationInput;
    this.startButton = startButton;
    this.pauseButton = pauseButton;
    if (callbacks) {
      // Se activan los callbacks
      this.onStart = callbacks.onStart;
      this.onTick = callbacks.onTick;
      this.onComplete = callbacks.onComplete;
    }
    // Al crear la instancia se esperan los eventos
    this.startButton.addEventListener("click", this.start);
    this.pauseButton.addEventListener("click", this.pause);
  }

  start = () => {
    if (this.onStart) {
      // Se comprueba tiene callback y ejecuta la función
      this.onStart(this.timeRemaining);
    }
    this.tick();
    this.interval = setInterval(this.tick, 20); // Guardamos el ID de setInterval
  };

  pause = () => {
    clearInterval(this.interval); // Para la ejecución del timer usando el ID
  };

  tick = () => {
    if (this.timeRemaining <= 0) {
      // Pausamos el timer si llego a 0 timeRemaining y ejecutamos onComplete
      this.pause();
      if (this.onComplete) {
        this.onComplete();
      }
    } else {
      this.timeRemaining = this.timeRemaining - 0.02; // Restamos 0.02seg a timeRemaining
      if (this.onTick) {
        this.onTick(this.timeRemaining); // Ejecutamos onTick para la animación
      }
    }
  };
  // Obtenemos en formato flotante el valor del input
  get timeRemaining() {
    return parseFloat(this.durationInput.value);
  }
  // Configura el tiempo restante con 2 digitos despues del punto
  set timeRemaining(time) {
    this.durationInput.value = time.toFixed(2);
  }
}

const durationInput = document.querySelector("#duration");
const startButton = document.querySelector("#start");
const pauseButton = document.querySelector("#pause");
const circle = document.querySelector("circle");

const perimeter = circle.getAttribute("r") * 2 * Math.PI;
circle.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", perimeter);

let duration;
const timer = new Timer(durationInput, startButton, pauseButton, {
  onStart(totalDuration) {
    duration = totalDuration; // Guardamos el tiempo total cuando el tiempo esta en pausa y se clickea el boton start
  },
  onTick(timeRemaining) {
    // Agrega el atributo a la etiqueta svg cada vez que se ejecuta tick y onTick
    circle.setAttribute(
      "stroke-dashoffset",
      (perimeter * timeRemaining) / duration - perimeter // formula para calcular la medida del atributo que dará el efecto animado
    );
  },
  onComplete() {
    console.log("Timer is completed");
  },
});
```

```css
html {
  background: url(https://source.unsplash.com/weekly?water);
  background-size: cover;
}

* {
  font: inherit;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Robot, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Fira Sans",
    "Droid Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
}

.timer {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dial {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
}

.timer input {
  display: block;
  border: none;
  width: 240px;
  font-size: 90px;
  text-align: center;
  background: transparent;
}

.timer button {
  border: none;
  font-size: 36px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: inherit;
}

.timer button:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.timer input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.controls {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1PKOgIY59xJ8Co8+NE6FZ+LOAZKjy+KY8iq0G4B3CyeY6wYHN3yt9PW0XpSriVlkMXe40PTKnXrLnZ9+fkDaog==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <title>Timer Back</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="timer">
    <div class="controls">
      <input id="duration" value="3" />
      <div>
        <button id="start"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></button>
        <button id="pause"><i class="fas fa-pause"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <svg class="dial">
        <circle
          r="190"
          cx="200"
          cy="200"
          fill="transparent"
          stroke="blue"
          stroke-width="15"
          transform="rotate(-90 200 200)"
        ></circle>
      </svg>
  </div>

  <script src="timer.js"></script>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que con cada clic en `start` vuelves a asignar la variable `duration` y eso solo debes hacerlo en la primera ejecución. Al volver de la pausa, simplemente continúas.

Basta una evaluación para que funcione como esperas:

```
if(!duration) { // No se ha iniciado el contador
    duration = totalDuration; // Asignar el valor correspondiente
}
```

```js
class Timer {
  constructor(durationInput, startButton, pauseButton, callbacks) {
    this.durationInput = durationInput;
    this.startButton = startButton;
    this.pauseButton = pauseButton;
    if (callbacks) {
      // Se activan los callbacks
      this.onStart = callbacks.onStart;
      this.onTick = callbacks.onTick;
      this.onComplete = callbacks.onComplete;
    }
    // Al crear la instancia se esperan los eventos
    this.startButton.addEventListener("click", this.start);
    this.pauseButton.addEventListener("click", this.pause);
  }
  start = () => {
    if (this.onStart) {
      // Se comprueba tiene callback y ejecuta la función
      this.onStart(this.timeRemaining);
    }
    this.tick();
    this.interval = setInterval(this.tick, 20); // Guardamos el ID de setInterval
  };

  pause = () => {
    clearInterval(this.interval); // Para la ejecución del timer usando el ID
  };

  tick = () => {
    if (this.timeRemaining <= 0) {
      // Pausamos el timer si llego a 0 timeRemaining y ejecutamos onComplete
      this.pause();
      if (this.onComplete) {
        this.onComplete();
      }
    } else {
      this.timeRemaining = this.timeRemaining - 0.02; // Restamos 0.02seg a timeRemaining
      if (this.onTick) {
        this.onTick(this.timeRemaining); // Ejecutamos onTick para la animación
      }
    }
  };
  // Obtenemos en formato flotante el valor del input
  get timeRemaining() {
    return parseFloat(this.durationInput.value);
  }
  // Configura el tiempo restante con 2 digitos despues del punto
  set timeRemaining(time) {
    this.durationInput.value = time.toFixed(2);
  }
}

const durationInput = document.querySelector("#duration");
const startButton = document.querySelector("#start");
const pauseButton = document.querySelector("#pause");
const circle = document.querySelector("circle");

const perimeter = circle.getAttribute("r") * 2 * Math.PI;
circle.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", perimeter);

let duration;
const timer = new Timer(durationInput, startButton, pauseButton, {
  onStart(totalDuration) {
    // Asignar solo al inicio
    if(!duration) {
        duration = totalDuration; // Guardamos el tiempo total cuando el tiempo esta en pausa y se clickea el boton start
    }
  },
  onTick(timeRemaining) {
    // Agrega el atributo a la etiqueta svg cada vez que se ejecuta tick y onTick
    circle.setAttribute(
      "stroke-dashoffset",
      (perimeter * timeRemaining) / duration - perimeter // formula para calcular la medida del atributo que dará el efecto animado
    );
  },
  onComplete() {
    console.log("Timer is completed");
  },
});
durationInput.addEventListener('change', () => {
    duration = parseInt(this.value) || 0;
});
```

```css
html {
  background: url(https://source.unsplash.com/weekly?water);
  background-size: cover;
}

* {
  font: inherit;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Robot, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Fira Sans",
    "Droid Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
}

.timer {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dial {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
}

.timer input {
  display: block;
  border: none;
  width: 240px;
  font-size: 90px;
  text-align: center;
  background: transparent;
}

.timer button {
  border: none;
  font-size: 36px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: inherit;
}

.timer button:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.timer input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.controls {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1PKOgIY59xJ8Co8+NE6FZ+LOAZKjy+KY8iq0G4B3CyeY6wYHN3yt9PW0XpSriVlkMXe40PTKnXrLnZ9+fkDaog==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <title>Timer Back</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="timer">
    <div class="controls">
      <input id="duration" value="3" />
      <div>
        <button id="start"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></button>
        <button id="pause"><i class="fas fa-pause"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <svg class="dial">
        <circle
          r="190"
          cx="200"
          cy="200"
          fill="transparent"
          stroke="blue"
          stroke-width="15"
          transform="rotate(-90 200 200)"
        ></circle>
      </svg>
  </div>

  <script src="timer.js"></script>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: gracias pero después cuando ingreso otro número al input la animación comienza desde otro punto no desde el inicio de la circunferencia

Comment: En tu pregunta no planteas esa posibilidad, ¿cómo ingresas otro número?

Comment: Es verdad no aclaré bien ese punto. Puedo cambiar de números seleccionando el valor 3 por defecto del input , borrarlo y agregar otro valor.

Comment: @JoséIgnacio, al final del código agregue evento `onchange` al input.

Comment: Excelente lo hiciste mas simple de lo que creía!